# VS2013 - Configuration requirement to use performance profiler on projects

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

In VS2013, I used to be able profile the performance of my projects of my c++ solution by intrumentation. Recently, I had to change a few things to make my project compile correctly in release, and now my projetss are now shown anymore as projet to profile in the dialog.

See: http://imgur.com/edit

I must have removed something required for the performance profiling of visual studio. I verified that I still have /DEBUG in the linker, and /PROFILE.

Anybody know what are the other requirement that could be missing ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

We have been moving to our new profiling platform the performance and diagnostics hub http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2013/07/12/performance-and-diagnostics-hub-in-visual-studio-2013.aspx . You can go to the Analyze -> Profiler -> New Performance Session. That will cause the performance explorer to open up. You can then right click on targets and select Add target project to get your project selected. Let me know if this does not work for you

Comment: This didn't work for me, Add target only lists the C# projects